# removing .html or .PHP URL extension using .htaccess not working

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

can anyone help me to remove .html or .php extension in URL.

I am trying this below code in my php project, but it is not working.
I have tried so many .htaccess codes, but nothing helps me..

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the `.htaccess` file really effective? For example, are you using Apache httpd? Did you enable the `rewrite` module?

Comment: I am running XAMPP and i have created in my htdocs folder, now .htaccess working for all my projects which are in htdocs, any way thank you FelisCatus

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Previously I also faced problem with removing .html or .php extension form URL.

I have a Solution Here

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

put the above code in .htaccess file, above code is for .php files.
for .html files go through the below code

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.html to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [L]
```

I just replaced the .php with .html

Hope it helps You.. :)

Comment: Is is possible to make it work for both without repeating the code for each extension?

Comment: You are genius!!! above 50-100 codes have been replaced, and this is the last one :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, gone through multiple questions and answers, neither worked until yours.