# Remove .php from URL but it should still be pointing towards the original file (mod-rewrite)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Dear fellow programmers

I'm pretty new to web development. Especially with the .htacces file. So I'm developing a webpage and I want to remove the .php file extensions. It is working for html but not for the php extension if I use the same code for it.

What I'm trying to achieve is when the user gets redirected to https://website.com/pong.php the URL gets changed to: https://website.com/pong. But the URL should still point to the first URL. Same for HTML files.

Thats the code I have for removing the html extension. There is allsow a line to redirect the page automatically to the https protocol (3rd line)

```
Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

I tried this to remove the php with but it didn't work. This is the line I added to my code.

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

I tried the answer of this question: [removing .html or .PHP URL extension using .htaccess not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32858568/removing-html-or-php-url-extension-using-htaccess-not-working)

But It generated this error while I tried to open the page: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: You have tried well here(in terms of being new and having a working Rules for html extension files), like what rule you have for html files you should have same kind of(in terms of Logic) for php extensions also. Now question comes how will you segregate which non-existing directories or files should rewrite to PHP file and which ones to rewrite to HTML files? If you could mention that Logic here we could help here for sure, thank you.

Comment: I do not fully  understand what you mean by that. But I want all the .html files to get the .html removed in the URL and the same for .php files

Comment: Ok, so you mean you are hitting link like: `http://localhost:80/test_singh.html` which should change URL to `http://localhost:80/test_singh`(which should be served by test_singh.html file only in backend) and same with php files? Could you please confirm once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your shown samples, could you please try following.
Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```